# How to force child elements to fit within a parent div width, desipte children using absolute width px values?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, resize

I am currently struggling with a div container with multiple children elements, some of which are images with absolute px width values.

The issue is resizing the parent and ensuring the content isn't cut off.

My current solution is:

```
function customResize(element){
    let parent = element.parentNode;
    element.style.width = parent.style.width;
    element.style.height = parent.style.height;        
}

$(window).resize(function (){    
    let elem = document.getElementById('contentContainerId');
    customResize(elem);
});
```

This uses a parent element of the container div (that automatically resizes correctly) as a guide, taking its width and height values and assigning them to the container div. This works for resizing, but for some reason, it's not fully correct.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

After some feedback, I'm noticing the container div is resizing correctly and staying to the width of its parent. However, its contents, despite shrinking, still gets cut far too much. See the example image below - green is the desired width, red is the problem area.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYXs.jpg)

Or perhaps more clear with this
[Example Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NkhX.jpg)

Comment: You can use CSS styles `(max)width` and `overflow-x` to solve this issue

Comment: Thanks, it's a case of how to use this in a way that it overwrites the absolute values previously assigned ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this w3schools page: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflow.asp

If you replace "hidden" with "scroll" and run it, you'll see how you can make your elements fixed size and scrollable.

As far as adapting to your situation, you may want to set the css `width` from the width before adding your images. You can do this like

```
var myDiv = ...;
let wid = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
myDiv.style.width = wid + "px";
```

And remember to add css style `overflow-x : "scroll"`

Comment: This is getting closer but still not quite there.  

Also typo on `let wid = myDiv.getClientBoundingRect().width;`
should be `let wid = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;`

Comment: "... not quite there" - what is getting closer and what is still not there?

Comment: see my edits to the original post